# polyfit on GPUArray is extremely slow

Tags: performance, matlab, gpu, linear-regression

I need to take a linear regression continuously over a large vector. I am using MATLAB's built-in function **polyfit** to fit a polynomial of degree one (a line) to the whole time series. I am trying to do this on the GPU because the process is slow on the CPU. But for some reason, whenever I use a GPUarray on the polyfit function it becomes even SLOWER, like extremely slow. Instead of gaining speed, I am making the process slower. What's wrong with my code?

```
function [SLOPE,INTERCEPT] = poly_slope(VECTOR,n_slope)

% Slope of past prices 
increments_percent = 0.1;  % only show increments of n%
percent_show = increments_percent; % show next percentage

SLOPE = zeros(length(VECTOR)-n_slope,1);
SLOPE_G = gpuArray(SLOPE);
INTERCEPT_G = gpuArray(SLOPE);

VECTOR_G = gpuArray(VECTOR);

for i=n_slope:length(VECTOR_G)
    take_slope = VECTOR_G(i-n_slope+1:i);
    take_slope_G = gpuArray(take_slope);
    x_G = gpuArray(1:n_slope);
    p = polyfit(x_G,take_slope_G,1);

    SLOPE_G(i) = p(1);
    INTERCEPT_G(i) = p(2);

    percent_comp = i/length(VECTOR_G) * 100;
    if percent_comp >= percent_show 
        fprintf('completed: %.2f percent\n',percent_comp)
        percent_show = percent_show + increments_percent;
    end
end

SLOPE = gather(SLOPE_G);
INTERCEPT = gather(INTERCEPT_G);

end
```

Comment: What are the parameters you use to call the function?

Comment: Basically if I have a time series vector X, and I want to continuously take a linear regression over 21 periods ago, I do: [m,b] = poly_slope(X,21); That will return N-21 different line equations (slope and intercept), where N = length(X).

Comment: A GPU is not the right processor for your problem, [explanations can be found in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627370/2732801)

Comment: Why? Isn't the GPU faster usually than the CPU?

Comment: Did you read the answer Daniel linked? That explains why a GPU is not necessarily faster than a CPU.

Comment: I didn't notice the link. Just read it, thanks, it's quite interesting.